# Using numpy to filter out multiple comment symbols

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to pull data from a file that has multiple comment symbols. The input file looks similar to:

```
# filename: sample.txt
# Comment 1
# Comment 2
$ Comment 3
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
# Comment 4
```

I can only seem to remove one comment type with the following code and can't find any documentation on how I might remove both.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('sample.txt',comments="#") # I need to also filter out '$'
```

Are there any alternative methods I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it possible to have data and a comment on the same line in your file?

Comment: No, this will not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this case, you need to resort to standard-python looping over the input, e.g. something like this:

```
data = []
with open("input.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line.startswith('#') or line.startswith('$'):
            continue
        data.append(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))

print data
```

output:

```
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30], [4, 40]]
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply use a list for comments, for example:

```
data = np.loadtxt('sample.txt',comments=['#', '$', '@'])
```

Comment: IT does work on numpy version 1.14.2 ! Too bad it doesn't work on genfromtxt as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a generator that will ignore the comments and then pass it to `np.genfromtxt()`:

```
gen = (r for r in open('sample.txt') if not r[0] in ('$', '#'))
a = np.genfromtxt(gen, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your lines either contain only a comment or your data, I'd just read in the file before processing it with numpy. Comment lines will be killed with regular expressions.

```
import re
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = re.sub(r'\s*[#\$].*\n', '', f.read())
data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), dtype=int, delimiter=',')
```

This will give you the desired numpy array `data`. Note that this approach will still work if a line (accidentally) starts with some whitespace followed by one of the comment characters.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at numpy.loadtxt code and it's not possible to use more than one character for comment, because they use str.split: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L790

I think you could load the file line by line, check if the line contains comment or not and then pass it to [numpy.fromstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the full `loadtxt` power, you can just modify it so it suits your needs. As David Marek noted, the line where comments are eliminated is [this one](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L790)

```
line = asbytes(line).split(comments)[0].strip(asbytes('\r\n'))
```

Becomes:

```
for com in comments:
    line = asbytes(line).split(com)[0]
line = line.strip(asbytes('\r\n'))
```

You would also need to change L717:

```
comments = asbytes(comments)
```

turns into:

```
comments = [asbytes(com) for com in comments]
```

If you want to keep full compatibility,

```
if isinstance(comments, basestring):
    comments = [comments]
```